# Finding path between 2 tree nodes

Tags: c++, tree

how can i print the path between any 2 query nodes in a tree not necessary a binary tree?
I have been using dfs and storing the paths in a vector for each query and printing it.
But if input query no. is too large q<=10^5,my algorithm which is of o(n*q)(may be not sure) complexity fails.n=no of nodes in the tree.Can anyone help me with some better optimization so that the time complexity reduces may be o(n*logq) or o(q*logn).n<=10^5.If any precomputation required suggest me so.

Comment: You can find lowest common ancestor in `O(log n)` using this technique for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_ancestor_problem#Jump_pointer_algorithm. So path between two nodes is path from the first node to LCA plus reversed path from the second node to LCA.

Comment: what will be the time complexity of that approach ?tell

Comment: Briefly: you calculate depth of both nodes, jump up from the deeper one until depth is not equal and then do something like binary search: `k` is `log(tree depth)`, jump up `2^k` if resulting nodes are not equal, otherwise do nothing, reduce `k` and repeat this step. Look here, LCA, method 4: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/16221

Comment: Does the approach will improve time complexity?

Comment: Yes, it takes `O(log n)` to know what the path is and if you need to print the path it will take also `O(path length)` (you just can't print path faster).

Comment: so the overall time complexity will be o(qlogn) according to you,isn't it?

Comment: That would require some `O(n log n)` precalculations, but yep, total is `O(n log n + q log n)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using either the UCS or A* algorithms? A* with a good heuristic will allow you to visit the least amount of nodes